# Storybook and Typescript - Fully custom args

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

According to Storybook doc you can do this:

```
const TableStory = ({ data, ...args}) => (
  <Table {...args}>
    {data.map((row) => (
      <TR>
        {row.map((item) => (
          <TD>{item}</TD>
        ))}
      </TR>
    ))}
  </Table>
);

export const Numeric = TableStory.bind({});
Numeric.args = {
  // This arg is for the story component
  data: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]],
  // The remaining args get passed to the `Table` component
  size: 'large',
};
```

I need to do something similar. This is my normal template:

```
const Template: ComponentStory<typeof StatsDisplay> = (args) => <StatsDisplay {...args} />;
```

I want it to be something like this:

```
const Template: ComponentStory<typeof StatsDisplay> = ({data, ...args}) => <StatsDisplay {...args} />;
```

And then I will do stuff with data.

So Typescript doesn't let me do this.
I get:
Property 'id' does not exist on type 'IProps'.

And ESLint gives me 'id' is missing in props validation.

I can't find any info about this anywhere on the internet. I hope someone can help me out.